# Convert DDS to PNG using linux command line

Tags: linux, command-line, conversion, png, dds

I need to convert thousands of DDS images to PNG format in Linux, preferably in command line.

Is there any program available for such task?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) reads but doesn't write DDS. And of course it reads and writes PNG.

From `identify -list format`:

> ...
>      DDS* DDS       r--   Microsoft DirectDraw Surface
>      ...
>      PNG* PNG       rw-   Portable Network Graphics (libpng 1.2.37)
>      ...

To convert a file (leaving the original intact):

```
convert test.dds test.png
```

To convert a directory full:

```
for file in *.dds
do
    convert "$file" "$(basename "$file" .dds).png"
done
```

Comment: Latest version of ImageMagick (6.8.7-4) writes DDS files as well